# AJAX fails using textarea and CKeditor widgets of yii2

Tags: ajax, yii2

following code will implement AJAX-Request as intended. Curiously, it's only working with yii2-method textinput(). Using yii2-method textarea() or even widget CKEditor doesn't work- Any ideas how to use AJAX-Request with more comfortable methods but textinput()?
Here is Controllercode:

```
<?php

namespace frontend\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\helpers\Json;
use backend\modules\app_einstellung\models\Textbaustein;
use yii\web\Controller;

class TextbausteinController extends Controller {

    public function actionBaustein($textId) {
        $text = Textbaustein::findOne($textId);
        echo Json::encode($text);
    }

}
```

Here is JQueryCode:

```
<?=
Dialog::widget();

$script = <<< JS
        $('#bez').change(function(){
        var textId=$(this).val();
        $.get('textbaustein/baustein',{textId:textId},function(data){
   var data=$.parseJSON(data);
  krajeeDialog.alert('Fügen Sie eventuell  erzeugte Mailvorlagen manuell(Copy&Paste) in Ihren Maileditor ein');
   $('#mailausgang-inhalt').attr('value',data.inhalt);
   });
        });

JS;

$this->registerJS($script);
?>
```

Following elements don't work with AJAX! Why??

```
   //echo $form->field($model, 'bodytext')->textarea();
/* echo $form->field($model, 'bodytext')->widget(\dosamigos\ckeditor\CKEditor::className(), [
 'preset' => 'full', 'clientOptions' => ['height' => 200],
   ]); */
```

Only this element works with AJAX! Why only this??

```
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <?=
        $form->field($modelTextbaustein, 'bezeichnung', ['addon' => [
                'prepend' => ['content' => 'Mailvorlagen']]])->widget(\kartik\widgets\Select2::classname(), [
            'data' => \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(Textbaustein::find()->orderBy('bezeichnung')->asArray()->all(), 'id', 'bezeichnung'),
            'options' => [
                'id' => 'bez'
            ],
            'pluginOptions' => [
                'allowClear' => true
            ],
        ]);
        ?>
    </div>

    works only with this:
    <?php    
         echo $form->field($model, 'bodytext', ['addon' => [
                        'prepend' => ['content' => 'Vorlage']]])->widget(TwbsMaxlength::className())
                ->textInput();
```

Rephrasing question:

As I think to attach an event handler on keypress event, in which fire the Ajax call only when the key is ENTER I coded like this but didn't succeed with it:

```
$script = <<< JS
$('#bez').keypress(function(e){
    if(e.which == 13) {
        var textId=$(this).val();
        $.get('textbaustein/baustein',{textId:textId},function(data){
            var data=$.parseJSON(data);
            $('#mailausgang-inhalt').attr('value',data.inhalt);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: `#bez` which element is this, i can see any where in the HTML reference

Comment: #bez is id of DropDownBox(Select2), which gives me values of database.U can see this id being defined above!

Comment: sorry for that, i overlooked it. so does it enters the js event defined or not , are there any errors in console when you load the page or when you change the option from the dropdown

Comment: No errors. I will get 200 response, alertBox will be triggered, but no takeover into texarea(), only takeover into textinput()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't know if this is the mistake , but i think thay in your AJAX response whe you set the value in the input  the "id" is wrong .

When you create a input in a form in yii2  his id by defaut is "**nameModel-attribute**" , then  in you case it is "textbaustein-bodytext", and in you JS  you must write like that .

```
// this set a attribute value , but  you dont see difference in you view , only in the code 
 $('#textbaustein-bodytext').attr('value',data.inhalt);

// this change  that you see
 $('#textbaustein-bodytext').text(data.inhalt);
//or
 $('#textbaustein-bodytext').val(data.inhalt);
```

> if you will like  write a different ID , you must write  like this
>
> ```
> echo $form->field($model, 'bodytext')->textarea(['id'=>'testId']);
> ```

Comment: Won't fix bug! Just triggering alertBox, but no takeover into textarea.

Comment: Great: Ur suggestion will takeover record into textarea. What about widget CKEditor?

Comment: Gave U reputation points for ur efforts helping me. Great job! Go ahead!!